# what is the meaning of "in the affections of" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

what is the meaning of "in the affections of" in this context?

> This strange, eccentric, and formidable man had his proper environment
>   in the 17th century, when his prototypes were holding moorland
>   meetings in Gallo way and avoiding, or possibly even attacking with
>   the arms of the flesh, the dragoons of Claverhouse. But, live when he
>   might, he was bound to write his nacre in some fashion on the annals
>   of his time. We read of his strenuous youth in Scotland, of his
>   rivalry with his friend Carlyle **in the affections of** the clever and
>   vivacious Jane Welsh, of his enormous walks and feats of strength, of
>   his short career as a rather violent school-teacher at Kirkcaldy, of
>   his marriage to the daughter of a minister in that town, and finally
>   of his becoming curate or assistant to the great Dr. Chalmers, who
>   was, at that time, the most famous clergyman in Scotland, and whose
>   administration of his parish in Glasgow is one of the outstanding
>   chapters in the history of the Scottish Church. In this capacity he
>   gained that man-to-man acquaintance with the poorer classes which is
>   the best and most practical of all preparations for the work of life.
>   Without it, indeed, no man is complete.

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Comment: He was a rival **in** love. Not as being "in love with" Jane Welsh, but "in the matter of love" for JW, in the affections of JW.

Answer (score 1):

This is from "The History of Spiritualism by Arthur Conan Doyle". The person being discussed is Edward Irving. The language is somwhat old-fashioned. If two men are rivals for the affections of a woman, they both wish to become her lover or marry her.